# django data not changing dynamically

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I wrote a django application to display some data fetched from mongodb in html template. All the order item ids are fetched with status `'APPROVED'`

models.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class GetNewOrders(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
        self.db = self.client['Flipkart']
        self.sale_order = list(self.db['sale_order'].find({'status':'APPROVED'}))

    def getOrderItemId(self):
        oiids = []
        for each in self.sale_order:
            oiids.append(each['orderItemId'])
        return oiids
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from orders.models import GetNewOrders

no = GetNewOrders()
oiids_new = no.getOrderItemId()

def orders(request):
    context_dict = {'oiids_new':oiids_new}
    return render(request, 'orders/orders.html', context_dict)
```

i used a for loop in my html file to display that data. If i change the status of a document to `'APPROVED'`, it does not reflect in my html until i restart the server. How to show the changed data in html without restarting django server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `GetNewOrders` is at module level it is only executed once - you need to move it into the function body:

```
def orders(request):
    no = GetNewOrders()
    oiids_new = no.getOrderItemId()

    context_dict = {'oiids_new':oiids_new}
    return render(request, 'orders/orders.html', context_dict)
```